# Angular 2 http.get to C# MVC with parameters

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Trying to place an http.get with parameters:

Angular2 service:

```
getAvailability(customerId) {
    var Customer = this.Customer.getValue();
    var data = ({ 'customerId': Customer.Id, 'eventId': eventId});
      console.log("service_data_body", data);  
    this.http.get("GetAvailability", data)
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe((x) => {
            console.log("callback succes");
        });

}
```

MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAvailability(int? customerId, int? eventId)
{
    var k = customerId; 
    var l = eventId;
    .......
 //some other implementation code....
}
```

I am not getting any error on build but on run time. While debugging, console log gives me the values but placing breakpoints, it seems that not been send to C#(var k and var l are null). So, the js service does not passing the variables the appropriate way.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: This is a GET. why does it look like you are trying to send data in the body? try including the data as url parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a GET. why does it look like you are trying to send data in the body? try including the data as url parameters.

```
getAvailability(customerId) {
    var Customer = this.Customer.getValue();
    var query = "?customerId=" + Customer.Id + "&eventId=" + eventId;
    console.log("service_data_query", query);  
    this.http.get("GetAvailability" + query)
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe((x) => {
            console.log("callback succes");
        });

}
```

Comment: Well, i am passing my "criteria", in order to get back an object. So, your solution worked pretty well for me(although I modified it, to encrypt the values in the url). Thank you for your time!